# Importing in XML from a file while using MarkupBuilder

Tags: groovy

I want to include data retrieved from an XMLParser and build a new file using the MarkupBuilder. I'm having trouble figuring out how this would work.

If I'm taking the wrong approach here, such as not using MarkupBuilder and using something else, let me know. Thanks!

**C:/file.xml:**

```
<externalData>
    <data><nestedData><soOnAndSoForth/></nestedData></data>      
</externalData>
```

**Code.groovy:**

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer).'root'("id":"foo") {

    File content = new File("C:/file.xml")

    def externalFile = new XmlParser(false,true,true).parse(content)
    // may or may not modify this external data...

    externalFile.each { elem -> ${elem} } 
    'moreData'('id':'myData')
}
println writer.toString()
```

**Expected result:**

```
<root id="foo">
    <externalData>
         <data><nestedData><soOnAndSoForth/></nestedData></data>     
    </externalData>
    <moreData id="myData">
</root>
```

**What I get:**

```
<root id="foo">
    <$ />
    <moreData id="myData">
</root>
```

Comment: See Tim Yate's answer on [How to add a node to groovy MarkupBuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11860503/5449431)

Comment: In the above answer, note the use of StreamingMarkupBuilder, mkp.yield, and XmlSlurper as opposed to XmlParser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a node to groovy MarkupBuilder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858266/how-to-add-a-node-to-groovy-markupbuilder)

Comment: And the question is double posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074542/using-data-from-xmlparser-while-building-static-xml-using-markupbuilder/42237671#42237671)